# How to reduce the size(bits) of an image in android

Tags: android, image, colors

Well, i am trying to reduce the size(bits) of an image, which will be taken using camera. I have already reduced it by reducing its height and width. But a lot of questions came infront.

1. IIsnt it possible that within same height & width- an image can contain more/less  resolutions. I mean- cant resolution vary within images which have same height & width?
2. Is there other properties of image/color, which we can change and make the total image size(bits) become less?
3. Any other solutions? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bitmap` to compress your image.
This can be done by calling;

```
Bitmap bm=//intialize your image here
FileOutputStream fos=//intialize your OutputStream here
bm.compress(Bitmap.JPEG, 50, fos)// the Number stands for the quality of the image, the format of the image can be changed if you want to
```

For further information see the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) here.